# React Login Form errors

Tags: reactjs

I Have a simple login form
Just Username and Password.

- the username input should update its value attribute on being changed.
- the password input should update its value attribute on being changed.
- `The button Submit should be disabled until both username and password fields are filled`. *I'm not sure how to do that.*

I have few errors on build. I'm not sure what I'm missing.
How do I fix this? sorry my react is just basic.

```js
import React from "react";
 

export default function LoginForm({ onSubmit }) {

this.state = { username: '', password: '' };
handleUsernameChange = (event) => this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
handlePasswordChange = (event) => this.setState({ email: event.target.value });

handleSubmitButton = () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;

    onSubmit(username-input, username-password);
  };
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input type="text" onChange={handleUsernameChange} id="username-input" placeholder="Username"/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input type="password" onChange={handlePasswordChange} id="password-input" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit(username-input, password-input)}>Submit</button>

      </form>
    );
 
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmit: (username, password) => {
      dispatch(signup(username, password));
    },
});
mapDispatchToProps(LoginForm);
```

errors:

```
 Line 9:1:    'handleUsernameChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 10:1:   'handlePasswordChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 12:1:   'handleSubmitButton' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 16:23:  'input' is not defined                 no-undef
  Line 21:42:  'handleUsernameChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 24:46:  'handlePasswordChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 27:49:  'username' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 27:58:  'input' is not defined                 no-undef
  Line 27:65:  'password' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 27:74:  'input' is not defined                 no-undef
  Line 35:16:  'signup' is not defined                no-undef
```

Comment: _few errors on build_ doesn't quite help, Can you post the detailed errors?

Comment: @Agney DONE sorry I assumed the errors for you gurus were obvious :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is immutable, so you're basically setting it to be an object containing only `email` when you handle the change. You should store each element in its own state, and then handle the disabled button state by implemetning the `useEffect()` hook.

Here's a refactored version (you'll need to handle the dispatching to your Redux store yourself, since we don't know if you're using Thunk or something similar as middleware):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
 
const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
    const [ buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled ] = useState(true);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(signup(username, password));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setButtonDisabled(
            ! (username !== '' && password !== '')
        );
     }, [ username, password ]);

    return (
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    onInput={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} 
                    id="username-input" 
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={ username }
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    onInput={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    id="password-input" 
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={ password }
                />
            </div>

            <button 
                disabled={ buttonDisabled }
                type="submit" 
                onClick={ handleSubmit }
                value="Submit"
            />
      </form>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: thanks great, really clear. I have 2 errors:   `Line 9:9:   'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 9:18:  'signup' is not defined    no-undef`

Comment: Please see this comment: *you'll need to handle the dispatching to your Redux store yourself, since we don't know if you're using Thunk or something similar as middleware*...